# Call to a member function fetch_() error in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blog";
$posts = $pdo->query($query);
$resultaat = $posts->rowCount();
$row = $resultaat->fetch_(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($resultaat > 0){
    while ($row){
        echo $row['titel'];
```

And i am getting this error:

> Call to a member function fetch_()

Can anyone help me out? (im new tot this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blog";
$posts = $pdo->query($query);
if (0 < $posts->rowCount()) {
    while ($row = $posts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

PHP PDO manual is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I am getting this message now: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc()

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blog";
      $posts = $pdo->query($query);
      if (0 < $posts->rowCount()) {
      while ($row = $posts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        ?><h2><?php echo $row['titel'];?> </h2>
```